# Sendgrid doesnt display deeplink like a clickable link

Tags: android, sendgrid, deeplink

I am trying to send a link via a email (sendgrid templates) but the link does not display as clickable or as a link at all. 
Here is my intent: `intent://myapphere#Intent;scheme=http;package=com.app;end`

and here is the link in my sendgrid template:

```
<a universal="true" href="intent://myapphere#Intent;scheme=http;package=com.app;end">
    Open App </a>
```

But when this is sent as an email both through the Node v3 api and through sendgrid dashboard, it appears like a text, not like a link. How can I sort this out so that Open App is clickable from the email?

Comment: This is valid issue, don't know why it was downvoted. Issue is persistent still, and across all clients because its issue not in sendgrid clients but its templates processing engine/backend.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

For anyone who was/is trying to figure this out, here is the approach I finally decided to go with.

1. Create a transactional sendgrid template with all the styling I wanted
2. Create a button with a placeholder - in this case {{code}}
3. Use a shortening url service like [tinyurl](https://tinyurl.com) to shorten the url and generate a http link. Finally inject the link into the template and send it to a user via the various API's

Answer (score 1):

SendGrid only tracks `http://` or `https://` as links. the `intent://` is not recognized as a link, and won't be tracked.

Comment: By track do you mean track for analytics? Because mine is strictly a display issue

Comment: Oh I see. SendGrid won't "track" it for Click-Tracking analytics purposes, but your link should still be valid on the platform you're using it on.

It might be that the SG template app is breaking on the `;` and other complex characters, since the tinyurl works.

Comment: @jacobmovingfwd It just removes the link, link is not there when it is of `intent://` form.